# How to display the `test case name` in mobile device screen while flutter integration test is being executed

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, watermark, flutter-integration-test, video-watermarking

Currently when we run the flutter integration test by `flutter test integration_test/app_test.dart`, we are seeing `Test Starting..` text in the mobile device/simulator screen(Screenshot Attached)

[image]

when we have multiple test cases in app_test.dart (Say 10 TCs)

1. In order to see which Test case is currently being executed, is there any way we can display the test case name in mobile device/simulator screen?
2. Or can we override Test Starting..?
3. Or can we add watermark?

Any help highly appreciated.!